GNOME apps not launching
My GNOME apps (e.g. nautilus, gedit, etc) are not working. When I click an application icon (or use ALT-F2 or a terminal to launch), the app name appears in the panel with the loading spinner, but then disappears and the window doesn't pop. On the dash, there isn't any indicator to show that the (pinned) app has a window, and the unpinned apps don't appear on the dash.
Other maybe relevant info:

GNOME desktop (3.3.2) on RHEL 8.
The machine is a VM, and I'm using vncserver and TigerVNC.
Some other desktop apps are working normally - those are the Java based ones.
The windows certainly aren't open on another workspace.
The machine is working perfectly normally via the CLI (SSH).
After I first installed the desktop environment, these apps had been working, but then stopped working a week or so. I don't recall what happened around the time it stopped working. I don't use these apps very frequently and wouldn't have noticed for some time.
The machine uses SELinux and my login is authenticated against Active Directory (but I don't know much about how these were set up by my company).
I've done all the latest updates.
I've checked journaltctl and tried launching from the terminal to check for error output on stdout/stderr but I don't see anything significant.

How can I troubleshoot further?
